# What is the law regarding magic in the BBC TV show Merlin?

Tags: tv, magic, merlin-bbc

I started watching Merlin and I've noticed that it isn't clear what law Uther exactly imposed.

- Is being a magician outlawed (Gaius is still alive because he stopped using magic), or
- Is using magic outlawed?
- If using magic is outlawed, why did they look for Mordred, who was too young to use magic (it was said that Merlin is special because he can use magic instinctively and others need "years of study")?

Comment: Which series? There were several on Merlin.

Comment: @DampeS8N: There is definitely no such consensus. See the [relevant Meta thread](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6/is-fantasy-in-spec-for-this-site).

Comment: If it is off topic then I'm sorry but usually SF and fantasy is spoken in one line (and on linked thread it seems that most answars and votes went to both) and I assumed that to be in line of the site.

Comment: @Gilles: I had looked back to http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2/51 and didn't realize so much had happened to your link since I had last been there. (see the second answer on it, which was the top one when I had last seen it) So I stand corrected and will vote to reopen. However, in light of this we should probably specify something in the FAQ about this. I'll do so as soon as I am able to. (or @Bill the Lizard can, if he ends up beating me to the punch)

Comment: This question could use improvement in the grammar arena, but it's definitely on-topic for this site, and I hope someone with Powers(TM) will reopen it ASAP.

Comment: Can someone more familiar with the series edit this, due to the grammar it's really hard to tell what is being asked.

Comment: I think he is referring to the TV Show Merlin. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merlin_(TV_series) not sure since I have seen it, but my dad watches it.

Comment: @percent20: Yes - I'm referring to this series.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Magic use is banned in Camelot, but, in S3E5 I believe, Uther told Gaius that he wanted Morgana saved, no matter what it took (he was telling Gaius to use magic).

Since Gaius is so loyal to Uther, and isn't openly using it, he is relatively safe, except for one episode where Uther thought Gaius was using magic (he protected Merlin) and was arrested and going to be killed.

Answer (score 13):

According to Uther, **magic is outlawed completely**.

That means:

- If you **can** do magic, and are discovered, you are put to death.
- If you **do** magic, and are discovered, you are put to death.
- If you **are** magic, and are discovered, you are put to death.

Basically if there is anything magical about you, and you're found out, you're dead - no matter who you are, how old you are, or your intentions.

In Mordred's case, he was a child of the druids, and they're just dripping with magic according to Uther, and therefore a threat.

Gaius is a special case; I don't think Uther realizes that Gaius *can* do magic, but he does know that Gaius has ties to the magical community.  I think he just assumes that Gaius will go seek out the black market magic in town when he says that he wants Gauis to use 'any means necessary' to cure Morgana.  (I seem to recall that there's another case where he gives Gaius this imperative; perhaps when Arthur was dying?  Everyone very nearly dies in this show so many times!)  Plus, he has absolute faith in Gaius' loyalty, which allows him to overlook any magical leanings.  Not to mention that whole using magic to have a son thing.  His hypocrisy is just limitless...

Answer (score 1):

Uther knows Gaius has studied and can do magic but he believes that Gaius came to realize magic was evil back when it was outlawed. It's not against the law to know magic if you learned before it was outlawed. As long as you have "realized the error of your ways" so to speak. It is just illegal to study or practice magic currently. And to be magic, like Merlin, Mordred, or Morgana.

Comment: You basically just contradicted both of the other answers. Or maybe you should clarify, because it's slightly vague what you're getting at.

Answer (score 0):

Also to note when Arthur becomes king he allows some places to use magic, but still has a relatively strong hold on the use of magic

Comment: Hi, could you please [edit] to expand on this answer a bit? At the moment it reads more like a comment ("Also to note ..."). At the very least, you should provide a reference, e.g. an exact quote, for Arthur doing this.